# Xubuntu netboot: vmlinuz not found

Tags: boot, networking, nfs, pxe

I try to boot linux via PXE-boot, but it keeps saying that `vmlinuz` can not be found. I wish there were more information on which exact filepath it's searching.

This is the relevant part of my `default` file:

```
LABEL      Xubuntu
MENU LABEL ^xubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64
    MENU DEFAULT            
    KERNEL boot/amd64/debian/xubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64/casper/vmlinuz
    APPEND root=/dev/nfs netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.0.192:/mnt/data/netboot/boot/ splash initrd=boot/amd64/debian/xubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64/casper/initrd boot=casper toram ---
MENU END
```

The TFTP-root in my `dnsmasq.conf` is at `/mnt/data/netboot`.
And the NFS-server is setup with the same directory: `/mnt/data/netboot 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0(ro, ...`

Yes, I was able to access the `vmlinuz` after mounting the root on another system (for testing). So the files **are** there.

What am I missing here?

Comment: 'Casper' is used in live environments. Not in installed operating systems. I have to state clearly that I have no experience in network-booting. Hoping this helps though.

Comment: do you get grub shell?

Comment: You mean that tab-option? Yes, I can edit these paths from there. But it does not help.